# How can I graph in using matplotlib/scikit learn?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am trying some code to make a learning curve :

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 7)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
estimator = LinearRegression()
estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predicted = estimator.predict(X_test)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.xlabel("Data")
plt.ylabel("MSE")
plt.ylim(-4, 14)
plt.scatter(X_train.ravel(), y_train, color = 'green')#<<<<<<<ERROR HERE
plt.plot(X_test.ravel(), y_predicted, color = 'blue')
plt.show()
```

Results in :

```
ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

Printing `X_train` and `y_train` shape output :

```
(1317, 11)
(1317,)
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to plot an 11 dimensional variable (x) against a 1 dimensional variable (y). You say you are trying to plot a learning curve. This implies you are training a model iteratively and showing the error after each iteration (or 5 iterations, or whatever). But that is not what you are plotting, you are training the model fully, then trying to plot the inputs (or whatever ravel() does to them) against the predictions. This won't work. You need to rethink what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you are trying to plot the response variable against 11 features on a 2d grid, which clearly isn't going to work. None of my following suggestions are going to achieve what you are attempting, since your model isn't learning iteratively instead you split, trained, tested. However if your If you merely want to plot each successive feature against your response you could do something like the following (I used pandas to organize my data)

```
data = DataFrame(np.random.normal(0,1, (1317, 11)), 
                     index=pd.date_range(
                     end= dt.datetime.utcnow(), 
                     periods=1317, freq='D'))

features = ['feature_{}'.format(x) for x in 
                    range(len(data.columns))]

data.columns = features
data['result'] = data.mean(1) + np.random.randn()

fig = plt.figure(figsize(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for feature in features:
    ax.scatter(data[feature], data['result'], c=numpy.random.rand(3,1))
```

Although I would probably just scatter your model (y_predicted) against y to visually validate my model.

[image]